# How to express $15.3\dot{9}$ in fractional form

Tags: fractions, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

In the number $15.3\dot{9}$, $9$ is repeated forever. If the number is rational then it can be expressed as a fraction (i suppose it is rational since it's an exercise for me to find it's rational representation?).

This is my attempt to solve it:
$$ x=15.3\dot{9} \iff 10x=153.\dot{9} $$
(i want $15.3\dot{9}$ therefore $138 + 15 +0.\dot{9}$)
$$10x=138 + 15 +0.\dot{9} $$
(i want $0.4$, since $0.4 +0.\dot{9}$ will give me $1.3\dot{9}$, i basically want the part .$3\dot{9}$)
$$10x=137.6 + 0.4 + 15 +0.\dot{9} \iff 10x=137.6 + 14 +1 +1.3\dot{9} \iff 10x = 137.6 + 1 +15.3\dot{9} \iff 10x = 138.6 + x \iff 9x = 138.6$$
$$ \therefore x = \frac{1386}{90} = \frac{154}{10} = \frac{77}{5}  $$

Now if i execute $\frac{77}{5}$ with software i get  $15.4$ not $15.3\dot{9}$. All other such exercises i've done give me the exact answer (not with infinite accuracy of course, but you understand that it would be correct, for example a software program should have given me $15.39999999999$ in order for me to realize that what i've done is correct).

What is the issue here? Am i wrong? Maybe the number is irrational?

Also is there any other simpler way to get the right answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong: $15.3\dot9=15.4$.

Comment: I always thought the standard way to write it was $15.3\bar 9$

Comment: I have seen this as an alternative way to write it.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: At first, I thought you meant that $15.3\dot{9}$ was an alternative way of writing $15.4$. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just observe and directly prove that

> $$
> 0.9999999999999999\cdots =1
> $$

Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...#Algebraic_proofs).